# Unknown ruby interpreter version

Tags: terminal, shell, textmate, ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have a MacBook Pro, running Mavericks, but I'm not too acquainted with its inner workings. I'm just a humble CS student.

After installing Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.0.0, I get this annoying message every time I open a new terminal window:

```
Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): textmate.
Could not load ruby textmate.
```

The message is in bright red, so it worries me. What can I do to fix it/get rid of it?

Thanks!

Edit: The commands I used to install the software are:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
sudo port -dv selfupdate
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
gem install rails -v 4.0.0
```

Edit 2: As it turns out, the message stopped showing, but I don't know what I did to make it stop. In any case - thanks for reading!

Comment: How did you install 1.9.3 and Rails? What shell startup files did you modify (`.bash_profile` maybe)?

Comment: I get a similar message when I `cd` into the directory of one of my Rails projects. It started suddenly and I cannot explain it.

Comment: Does `grep 'rvm use textmate' ~` return anything? You have `rvm use textmate` somewhere in the initialisation scripts.

Comment: Hi Leonid - grep 'rvm use textmate' ~ returns: "grep: /Users/mchen: Is a directory"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this:

```
rvm alias delete textmate
rvm alias create textmate 1.9.3
```

Comment: Please explain what this does when answering

Comment: sorry, it was the wrong version on my answer. my bad, i fixed it. i thought that it was obvious that it remove the rvm rubie alias of texmate and add a new one with the current ruby version he's using, thats why it could work for him